# GridView Show 4 out of 10 columns with custom headers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview.Datasource = someDatatable

I want to show 5 out of 10 columns with FirstName as "First Name"

Is there a quick way to do it instead of us using itembound functions?

Another thing is.. I put some asp:bound fields but then the datasource field still come in addittion to my databound fields.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for that property and your replies. I wanna add a checkbox in front of the rows too. or my own control. <columns> wont allow me to do that. In sum, I would need a mix of bound fields and a custom checkbox or other control. Is this combination possible?

Comment: Yes - you can use a TemplateField to add a checkbox to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another thing is.. I put some
>   asp:bound fields but then the
>   datasource field still come in
>   addittion to my databound fields.

May be set property

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>
```

and after that set column that you wish to present as databound fields.

Comment: I missed that prt of the question.  + 1 for giving the "rest of the answer".

Comment: Thanks for that property and your replies. 
I wanna add a checkbox in front of the rows too. or my own control. <columns> wont allow me to do that. 
In sum, I would need a mix of bound fields and a custom checkbox or other control. 
Is this combination possible?

Comment: You can try :
<asp:GridView id="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderText="Column name">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<ctr:MyCtr id="ctrId" runat="server"/><asp:TextBox id="tb" runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
and then in 
void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if((e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)&&(e.Row.RowIndex>-1))
{
 MyCtr ctr = (MyCtr)e.Row.FindControl("ctrId");
 TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("tb");
}
}

Answer (score 2):

First to correct this:  *I put some asp:bound fields but then the datasource field still come in addittion to my databound fields.*  You need to set :

```
  AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

Then if you do use bound columns you can set the HeaderText for each column to be whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [TemplateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn.aspx) instead of [BoundColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.aspx)

Another would be to do this in code-behind after the DataBind() is called.

```
...
myGridView.DataBind();
myGridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
myGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "First Name";
```

Personally, I like the TemplateColumn approach.  I almost never us what the drag and drop designer gives me without at least some modifications.

**Edit - added**

I missed the part of the question where the columns are adding automatically.  As others have answered, this can be fixed by setting AutoGenerateColumns = false on the GridView.